# reactjs autosuggest suggestion list detached from input

Tags: css, reactjs, autosuggest

I created an autosuggest usting react-autosuggest, now I'm trying do design the layout. I took a css from an [example](https://codepen.io/ciaranm87/pen/rLNGaJ) which seems to work fine.

when I copied this css to my project the suggestion list completely detached from the input of the autosuggest as shown in the image below:

[image: detached list from input]

I also tried to move the div in the example but the list follows the input (as it should)

here is the css from codepen which I tried to use:

```
.react-autosuggest__container {
  position: relative;
}

.react-autosuggest__input {
  width: 240px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.react-autosuggest__input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.react-autosuggest__container--open .react-autosuggest__input {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestions-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestion--focused {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `position: relative` in `react-autosuggest__suggestions-container`

Answer (score 1):

I think this css only works for the sandbox as used in the example. Especially

```css
.react-autosuggest__suggestions-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
```

This means that the suggestions container is always shown 51px from the top of your page. Due to other things on your page the input is probably in the way and pushed aside, since it doesn't has the `position: absolute` attribute.

I don't know if you're using something like a grid system or another way to manage positions of elements on your website? You might consider using that instead of defining position with `px`s.

Comment: I tried to delete it but it still behaves the same. How should I do it if I want it to be exactly under the input, no matter where I put the autosuggest component?

Comment: Based on the code you've provided I can't say what else it would be. Maybe a mistake in your HTMlL, maybe clashes in other parts of your css.

Comment: I placed my component in the index page that comes with a default new reactjs app

Answer (score 0):

try to add this

```
.react-autosuggest__suggestions-container--open {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 51px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```